# Read MP3 Tags with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mp3

Does someone know a library that I can use to read MP3 tags in Silverlight 3?
In WPF I was using taglib, but obviously I cannot reference it in Silverlight projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taglib doesn't contain any unsafe code.  Perhaps you can recompile it (with a few minor alterations maybe) to work in silverlight.

Have you tried just using Taglib's code? There's a decent chance it'll work without too much hassle.

***Edit:*** Yes, I mean TagLib#.  I just tried, and there are a few minor issues which were fixable in 15min.  (You'll need to define ICloneable, remove a bunch of unnecessary Serialization constructors for exceptions, remove the last parameter on string.Split(char[],int) calls, that's about it.)

Note that unless someone else has fixed it, there's a minor bug in Taglib#'s Id3v2 unsynchronization code.  You can ignore it and fail to parse a few id3v2 tags, or you can use the same workaround I did: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=593138#c4 - I know, I should submit a patch, but time and all...

Comment: do you mean taglib#? because taglib is not a .NET library, so won't be usable from Silverlight

Comment: Yes I mean taglib#. Is it open source? If so, I will have a look at the code...Still, hopefully somebody knows an existing SL library.

Comment: I just tried to port the Code to Silverlight, but there are just too much incompatibilities, so that I would have to rewrite a lot :(

Comment: I tried porting it to SL2 btw, and that worked without a hitch.

Comment: The issues look complex, but really, they're not.  If you can't figure it out, contact me again, and I'll mail you the updated code.

Comment: You were right, I fixed everything and now I try creating a TagLib File from a stream via a TagLib Interface (per default I would have to pass an absolute path). If I still have problems I will contact you again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Eamon - did you post your updated code anywhere?  Would love to see it.

Comment: Timing, timing - I just cleaned out my dev-experiments and deleted the above modifications three days ago; so no, I don't have the code anymore.  It is, however, truly quite easily done - just set the output target to silverlight and fix the resulting compile errors.  There are a bucketload; but almost all are trivial; the only slightly complex issues are mentioned above - define ICloneable, remove the last parameter from string.Split, and remove unsupported serialization constructors (which you don't need).  That's it!